# mysql: Select Max value and delete other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the row with the maximum status value for each employee_id and keep only one record for employee_id

If status is equal for the same employee id then pick one and delete the other, Thank you and appreciated

Table:

| ID | Type | Status | emplyee_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | A | 0 | 10 |
| 2222 | A | 1 | 10 |
| 3333 | B | 0 | 20 |
| 4444 | B | 0 | 20 |

Desired out but

| ID | Type | Status | Emplyee ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2222 | A | 1 | 10 |
| 3333 | B | 0 | 20 |

Comment: what have you tried so far? share your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this ...

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM employer_status emp,
    (SELECT emp1.emplyee_id, MAX(emp1.id) id
        FROM employer_status emp1, 
            (SELECT emp3.emplyee_id AS emplyee_id, MAX(emp3.status) AS STATUS
               FROM employer_status emp3
               GROUP BY emp3.emplyee_id
            ) AS emp2
        WHERE emp1.emplyee_id = emp2.emplyee_id
        AND emp1.status = emp2.status
        GROUP BY emp1.emplyee_id
    ) emp4
WHERE emp.id = emp4.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your table is called: employer_status

this could work:

```sql
SELECT emp1.*
FROM employer_status emp1, 
    (SELECT emp.emplyee_id, MAX(emp.id) id
    FROM employer_status emp
    GROUP BY emp.emplyee_id
    ) AS emp2
WHERE emp1.id = emp2.id;
```

Comment: *I need to get the row with the maximum status value for each employee_id....* Where is the status in your query?